# If $\bigcup\{A_\alpha \,:\, \alpha \in\Lambda\} \ne \emptyset$, then for each $\beta \in\Lambda$, $A_\beta \ne\emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing

> *Prove or disprove*, where $A$,$B$ are sets:
>
> a)Let $\{A_\alpha\, :\, \alpha \in \Lambda\}$ be an indexed collection of sets. If $\bigcup\{A_\alpha \,:\, \alpha \in\Lambda\} \ne \emptyset$, then for each $\beta \in\Lambda$, $A_\beta \ne\emptyset$.
>
> b) $A \subseteq (B \setminus A)$ if and only if $A = \emptyset$.

For (a) , I think it is false:
let $A_1=\{1,2\}$, and $A_2=\emptyset$ , $A_3=\{5\}$

So, $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 =\{1,2,5\}$

For (b) , I think it is true , and I know how I can prove it.

Could you please check these for me?

Comment: Your counterexample for (a) works and (b) is indeed true.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @ G. Sassatelli , Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your counterexample for (a) works and (b) is indeed true.